# Condition check for Class variables inside drools rule not working

Tags: java, drools

I am having the following class

```
  public class SeniorClass {

    List<Students> stud;
    String highScorerMath;
    String highScorerChemistry;
    String highScorerPhysics;
    String highScorerEnglish;
    int studentPassCount=2;

    public String getHighScorerMath() {
        return highScorerMath;
    }

    public void setHighScorerMath(String highScorerMath) {
        this.highScorerMath = highScorerMath;
    }

    public String getHighScorerChemistry() {
        return highScorerChemistry;
    }

    public void setHighScorerChemistry(String highScorerChemistry) {
        this.highScorerChemistry = highScorerChemistry;
    }

    public String getHighScorerPhysics() {
        return highScorerPhysics;
    }

    public void setHighScorerPhysics(String highScorerPhysics) {
        this.highScorerPhysics = highScorerPhysics;
    }

    public String getHighScorerEnglish() {
        return highScorerEnglish;
    }

    public void setHighScorerEnglish(String highScorerEnglish) {
        this.highScorerEnglish = highScorerEnglish;
    }

    public int getStudentPassCount() {
        return studentPassCount;
    }

    public void setStudentPassCount(int studentPassCount) {
        this.studentPassCount = studentPassCount;
    }

    public List<Students> getStud() {
        return stud;
    }

    public void setStud(List<Students> stud) {
        this.stud = stud;
    }


}
```

When I am inserting a data related to this class into Drools session and fire rules. Following rule doesn't seem to be working.

```
rule "Students passed count"
lock-on-active true
dialect "mvel"
dialect "java"
salience 0
when
        $sc : SeniorClass(studentPassCount > 0);        
then
        System.out.println(" Rule 6: Total no. of Students passed are: " + $sc.getStudentPassCount());
end
```

I am not sure why my condition check of "studentPassCount > 0" not coming as true even though in class I have set this variable value as 2. Can anyone suggest me solution for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Did you insert a fact of class SeniorClass into working memory?

Are you sure that setStudentPassCount wasn't called with a value of <= 0?

Are there any other rules with lock-on-active set to true in your rule base? **I strongly suggest that you do not use this attribute unless there is no other way.**

Are you sure that your rules are syntactically correct so that the rule base contains this rule (and others)?

Did you call fireAllRules? (Did you observe that other rules fire?)

Why do you use contradicting rule attribute values for `dialect`? **Stick to one of them.**

Comment: Yes, I have inserted SeniorClass into working memory as my other rules are working fine.

studentPassCount will always have value 0 or greater.

Yes, there are other rules with lock-on-active as true

Yes, they are Syntactically correct as I am not getting any Exception.

Yes, I have call fireAllRules.

and I am using both dialects just to implement functionality of both.

Comment: The attribute lock-on-active being on a set of rules may inhibit this rule to fire. - You can't use `dialect` with the intent of using features of both; it is either-or. - Anyway, it's impossible to tell from the code and your answers what really goes wrong. Please edit your question and provide the code for creating the session and for inserting facts. Either, check that the problem persists with this rule being the only one, or display all rules. In short: all code to reproduce the problem, and make sure to state the Drools version.

Comment: You can find my code here: https://github.com/gomzeegautam/sg-usersearch/tree/master/sg-usersearch and I am using Drools: 5.3

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not going to dig through several hundred lines of code. Reduce this to the minumum amount of code - just Java and DRL, no XML - reproduce the problem. - However, I suggest that you avoid lock-on-active, and use just one dialect. (See edits to my answer.)